# trigonometric regression in R

Tags: r, regression, trigonometry

How can I do a trigonometric regression using R?

For example, for the data

```
t<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y<-c(7.53,3.85,3.22,6.40,7.42,3.43,1.60,7.26,7.33,3.20,2.67,6.74)
```

how can i fit a model in the form

```
$Y_t=\beta+\alpha \cos(\frac{2\pi}{p})t+\gamma \sin(\frac{2\pi}{p})t$  p=4 and is the period
```

to find estimations for the parameters \beta \alpha and \gamma ?

i have tried to do

```
modelo<-lm(y~cos((2*pi)/p)+sin((2*pi)/p))
```

but it dosen't work.

Comment: what is `p` (the period)?  Are you trying to estimate it too (in which case this isn't really a linear model), or does it have a known value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include `t` in the regression:

```
p <- 4
modelo<-lm(y~cos((2*pi*t)/p)+sin((2*pi*t)/p))
```

Plot data and predictions:

```
plot(t,y)
dpred <- data.frame(t=seq(1,12,length=51))
dpred$y <- predict(modelo,newdata=dpred)
with(dpred,lines(t,y))
```